# What is Script Binding, and How is it done?

Tags: c++, javascript

I have heard such thing as Script Binding - binding Javascript or lua with API's from C++ or Objective-C. 
I want to know more about it- however Google has strangely proven unuseful for this.

How is it done? - it OK if I get pointed to other sources, but, just how? 
I never knew a Scripts jitter could interact with compiled libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.js appears to just spin up an instance of v8, parse a JavaScript file and extract a function object from it (in C++) then wrap some external C++ libraries in a v8 object and pass it into the function and call it. From there on out, it's bootstrapped with it's own bridge.